# How can I implement a choose folder option in Uploadify?

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

Uploadify works great, and I love it.  However, I just can't figure out how to make a dropdown list to select what upload folder to choose.  I want my user to be able to select a folder to upload the file to.  Anyone know a good way to do this?  Preferably simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slight mistake ....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : $("#folder").val(),
    'auto'      : true
  });
}); // should not be here - goes above </script>

  $("#folder").change(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadifySettings('folder',$("#folder").val());
  });
</script>
```

---

my code (ignore locations of script / also I set folder to first option of #folder which happens to be dubstep on my dropdown)

js head section

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'uploader'          : 'upload/uploadify.swf',
        'script'            : 'upload/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg'         : 'upload/cancel.png',
        'folder'            : 'upload/dropbox/dubmin',
        'fileExt'           : '*.mp3',
        'fileDesc'          : '.mp3 files only',
        'multi'             : true,
        'queueSizeLimit'    : 4,
        'queueID'           : 'queue',
        'sizeLimit'         : 52428800,
        'wmode'         : 'transparent'
        });

    $("#folder").change(function () {
        var path = "upload/dropbox/" + $(this).val();
        $('#file_upload').uploadifySettings('folder', path);
    });
    /* begin test to see if js switching to correct folder (remove or comment out section when done) */
    $('#test').click(function(){
        var folderz = $('#file_upload').uploadifySettings('folder');
        alert("folder is set to: "+folderz);
    });
    /* begin test to see if js switching to correct folder */
});
</script>
```

html code

```
<select id="folder" name="folder">
    <option value="dubtem">Dubstep</option>
    <option value="liqmin">Liquid</option>
    <option value="drknro">Neuro</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="test">Which Folder?</button>
</p>
<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
<div id="queue"></div>
<a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifyUpload();"><img src="submit.png" id="submit_img"></a>
```

comment out or erase test section from either html or js when done with it.

Comment: I don't see how this is a simple answer that asker has asked for. I also don't understand why asker changed answer to the vote, when clearly my answer was there in the first place. Asker with multiple accounts?

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#file_upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
    'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
    'folder'    : $("#folder").val(),
    'auto'      : true
  });
});

$("#folder").change(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadifySettings('folder',$("#folder").val());
});
</script>
```

and make a html select with folder values.

```
<select id="folder">
    <option value="/uploads">Uploads</option>
    <option value="/videos">Videos</option>
    <option value="/music">Music</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I did now.  Sorry first question.